Clustering using Python
I have data that resembles this:
import pandas as pd
import random
random.seed(901)
rand_list1= []
rand_list2= []
rand_list3= []
rand_list4= []
rand_list5= []

for i in range(20):
    x = random.randint(80,1000)
    rand_list1.append(x/100)
    
    y1 = random.randint(-200,200)
    rand_list2.append(y1/10)
    y2 = random.randint(-200,200)
    rand_list3.append(y2/10)
    y3 = random.randint(-200,200)
    rand_list4.append(y3/10)
    y4 = random.randint(-200,200)
    rand_list5.append(y4/10)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Rainfall Recorded':rand_list1, 'TAXI A':rand_list2, 'TAXI B':rand_list3, 'TAXI C':rand_list4, 'TAXI D':rand_list5})

df.head()


   Rainfall Recorded    TAXI A  TAXI B  TAXI C  TAXI D
0               5.21    13.7    -5.0    -14.2   9.8
1               2.39    -0.3    18.8    4.8     -6.4
2               8.09    15.0    -3.6    18.6    12.7
3               5.79    -0.2    14.6    0.9     3.8
4               7.48    10.9    9.0     15.4    -16.5

Given the Rainfall recorded in our region in centimeters, these are the % change in earnings reported by TAXI drivers surveyed. Can I use K MEANS CLUSTERING to determine whether the TAXIS operated in our locality or not? Suppose there is relationship between Rainfall recorded and the Earnings change.
I have simple code got from web source:
km = KMeans(n_clusters=2)
y_predicted = km.fit_predict(df[['TAXI','Rainfall Recorded']])
y_predicted

But I am unsure what transformations need to be done before using this code.

import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
import random

random.seed(901)
rand_list1 = []
rand_list2 = []
rand_list3 = []
rand_list4 = []
rand_list5 = []

for i in range(20):
    x = random.randint(80, 1000)
    rand_list1.append(x / 100)
    
    y1 = random.randint(-200, 200)
    rand_list2.append(y1 / 10)
    y2 = random.randint(-200, 200)
    rand_list3.append(y2 / 10)
    y3 = random.randint(-200, 200)
    rand_list4.append(y3 / 10)
    y4 = random.randint(-200, 200)
    rand_list5.append(y4 / 10)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Rainfall Recorded': rand_list1, 
    'TAXI A': rand_list2, 
    'TAXI B': rand_list3, 
    'TAXI C': rand_list4, 
    'TAXI D': rand_list5
})

# Number of clusters
k = 2

# Function to apply k-means to each row
def cluster_row(row, n_clusters):
    # Extract the taxi data
    taxi_data = row[['TAXI A', 'TAXI B', 'TAXI C', 'TAXI D']].values.reshape(-1, 1)
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters, random_state=0)
    kmeans.fit(taxi_data)
    return kmeans.labels_

# Apply the function to each row and store the cluster labels
df['Taxi Clusters'] = df.apply(lambda row: cluster_row(row, k), axis=1)

print(df)

This gives Taxi Clusters for each row of the entries made recording the rainfall received in our locality.

You can use the StandardScaler() class, and perform fit_transform(), which is a single call for fitting and transforming, then use fit_predict().
SS = StandardScaler()
ftr = SS.fit_transform(df)

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=901)
df['Cluster'] = kmeans.fit_predict(ftr)


Code
import pandas as pd
import random
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


random.seed(901)
rand_list1 = [random.randint(80, 1000) / 100 for _ in range(20)]
rand_list2 = [random.randint(-200, 200) / 10 for _ in range(20)]
rand_list3 = [random.randint(-200, 200) / 10 for _ in range(20)]
rand_list4 = [random.randint(-200, 200) / 10 for _ in range(20)]
rand_list5 = [random.randint(-200, 200) / 10 for _ in range(20)]


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Rainfall Recorded': rand_list1,
    'TAXI A': rand_list2,
    'TAXI B': rand_list3,
    'TAXI C': rand_list4,
    'TAXI D': rand_list5
})


SS = StandardScaler()
ftr = SS.fit_transform(df)

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=901)
df['Cluster'] = kmeans.fit_predict(ftr)
print(df)


plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.scatter(df['Rainfall Recorded'], df['TAXI A'], c=df['Cluster'], cmap='viridis')
plt.show()


Prints
    Rainfall Recorded  TAXI A  TAXI B  TAXI C  TAXI D  Cluster
0                5.21     3.8     4.5     1.8    13.8        1
1                7.55    13.4     7.2    17.4    19.2        1
2                3.81    10.9    14.9    -1.1    16.0        1
3                1.97     9.0    -4.8   -16.0    16.5        1
4                6.77    15.4    16.4    17.7   -18.7        1
5                2.39   -16.5    -4.5     6.5    15.4        1
6                4.75     5.7     2.3    10.0     2.3        1
7                8.57   -14.1    17.4    -1.8   -16.8        0
8                5.77    -4.8    -0.5    16.3    10.1        1
9                3.52    -0.8     9.1    15.7    -9.5        1
10               8.09    14.8   -11.6     2.1   -19.0        0
11               7.80   -14.5   -19.8    -4.2    -0.7        0
12               9.23    16.3    -3.6    11.0   -19.7        0
13               4.08    -1.9    10.9    -3.7     6.8        1
14               8.52    11.2   -17.9     5.5     3.5        0
15               7.34   -14.7    12.4   -19.1   -13.0        0
16               5.79    14.1    -6.8    17.5     1.6        1
17               4.77   -19.2    12.9    -2.6     8.0        1
18               7.73     0.8    -8.1     5.2   -11.4        0
19               4.99     8.0   -14.6    -1.7    18.6        1



I think this methods assumes all Taxis operated together in the same region as each other every time. The taxis could have operated separately. Each row of the input could be clustered separately resulting in groups of taxis operating in our region forming a cluster and other group which operated outside our region forming a cluster.

Consider the input dataframe converted from wide to long form for instance. This is the kind of transformation I meant in the question.
